# Google Fusion Tables With Maps - Link Table field to Map Info Window

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I'm pretty much a rookie to using Google Fusion Tables/maps. We have a business directory with company names and addresses. I can get the geocoded map markers for each of their locations to display side by side with the Table "facility name" column. How do I code the facility names so the user can click the company/facility name and jump to the specific map marker info box for that facility in the map? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Once the user clicks on the company name, you can create a new [InfoWindow object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows) manually. Then set it's position and content and finally put it on the map:

```js
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas');
 var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
 var coordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(37.5, -122.1);
 infoWindow.setPosition(coordinates);
 infoWindow.setContent('Company/Facility XY');
 infoWindow.open(map);
```

There is an [InfoWindow example from Google](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/open_infowindow), that even uses geocoding and a spatial query to get the closest hit from the database.