# Selecting a polygon in a FusionTablesLayer from Javascript

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have a map with FusionTablesLayer for my fusion table. The resulting map is a set of coloured polygons. If the user clicks on a polygon, the data associated with this polygon is displayed in the form of a info window. Can I select a particular polygon from javascript instead of via a mouse click? For example, if I have a chart with the same data, it would be nice to update the map for the current chart selection.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to show the InfoWindow, when a certain element is selected in the chart. Right? Maybe [my answer from another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748211/google-fusion-tables-with-maps-link-table-field-to-map-info-window/11820249#11820249) helps you.

Comment: @Odi When I select an item in the chart and establish its row number, should I then make a query which requests the center point of the associated polygon or is there a way of selecting the nth polygon in my layer without the need of a point.

Comment: I don't know of a way to selected the nth polygon on the layer (at least not when you are using the FusionTablesLayer). I'd try the approach with the query ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted any code so this is just a guess. My approach would be:

1. Create a unique key for each polygon in your FT
2. Associate those keys with your charts or links
3. Create a special FT layer to handle the highlighting with a unique color
4. For a chart or link click set the query options for your highlight layer using the unique key to retrieve the correct polygon overlaid on the existing polygon with your unique color.